# Exclude newly created Makefile from .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have few folders in git repo. Every folder contains an "arm" folder which is included to `.gitignore` file. But I have a few Makefiles in "arm" folder and in subfolders of arm folder. When I make changes in Makefiles which is under source control `git status` show me the changes. But if I create new subfolder in "arm" folder and add Makefile `git status` output is empty. How can I change `.gitignore` file to see untracked Makefiles in `git status` output?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder) might help you! Also post your .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add Makefile to your Git using the command line:

```
git add -f Makefile
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the Makefile overriding the `.gitignore` configuration, with `git add -f arm/Makefile`, making git still ignore what is in the folder except for the Makefile that is tracked by it anyway now.

Or you can add the exception for Makefiles on the `.gitignore`, like:

```
arm/*
!arm/Makefile
```

Comment: Be aware that an exception will not work for Makefiles in subfolders!

Comment: I try that but it does not work for untracked files.